# Rsample - nested_cv (ggplot2 - geom_tile) -> graphical visualization of nested CV

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am working on a paper where I am using nested-cross-validation. I am keen to present a graphical representation of such.
For the data partition, I am using the package rsplit. @Topepo presents a great vignette here: https://tidymodels.github.io/rsample/reference/tidy.rsplit.html

```
#Nested Group
library(rsample)
theme_set(theme_bw())
library(rsample)
library(patchwork)
cv <- nested_cv(iris, outside = group_vfold_cv(data = iris, group = "Species", v = 3), inside = rsample::bootstraps(times = 5, apparent = F))
tidy_cv<-tidy(cv)
innerplot<- ggplot(tidy_cv, aes(x = inner_Resample, y = inner_Row, fill = inner_Data)) +
geom_tile() + facet_wrap(~Resample) + scale_fill_brewer()

validation<- ggplot(tidy_cv, aes(x = Resample, y = Row, fill = Data)) +
geom_tile() + facet_wrap(~Resample) + scale_fill_brewer()

validation + innerplot
```

However, what I am actually trying to achieve is a stack of geom_tiles. Basically, something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTSPw.png

However, it would be facet_wrap ~Resample.
Is it clear what I am trying to do?
[Visual Representaiton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgC7R.png)
Cheers

Comment: There seems to be an error in your `cv <- nested_cv` line.

Comment: edit made, thank @novica